# Visual Studio 2015 code analysis shows diffrent errors when files opened

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-analysis

I have a C# 6 project where I use StyleCop.Analyzer and some other default Visual Studio code analysis. I noticed some strange behavior when I build solution without opening any file then I get 1 error, but when I open some files then I get 3 errors and 9 warnings. Now I close files and I still have 3 errors and 9 warnings – I need to run few times the rebuild action to get 1 error again.
 So the question is why do I get different amount of errors when I don't have any opened file? Why do I need some extra rebuild action to return to this 1 error.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the exact same thing - now VS 2017 Community 15.7.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-enable-and-disable-full-solution-analysis-for-managed-code

To toggle full solution analysis:

1. To open the Options dialog box, on the menu bar in Visual Studio choose Tools > Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, choose Text Editor > C# or Basic > Advanced.
3. Select the Enable full solution analysis check box to enable full solution analysis, or clear the box to disable it. Choose OK when you're done.

I thought I had no warnings...now I have a few more!